# PKCS11Exception: CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID How to integrate Java and PKCS11 and GCP Cloud KMS?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, pkcs#11, google-cloud-kms, sunpkcs11

I'm trying to use GCP Cloud KMS for establishing mTLS. For this purpose I'm preparing PoC of integration Java + JCE + PKCS11 + Cloud KMS integration lib + GCP Cloud KMS.
Stack:

- OpenJDK 1.8
- SunPKCS11 Provider
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kms-integrations
- GCP Cloud KMS

As a result I have an exception:

```
Private key:  SunPKCS11-KmsHSM RSA private key, 3072 bitstoken object, sensitive, unextractable)
I20220812 18:55:30.725561    12 logging.cc:137] returning 0x70 from C_DecryptInit due to status INVALID_ARGUMENT: at crypter_ops.cc:33: mechanism 0x1 is not valid for operation decrypt [type.googleapis.com/kmsp11.StatusDetails='CK_RV=0x70']
I20220812 18:55:30.726071    12 logging.cc:137] returning 0x70 from C_DecryptInit due to status INVALID_ARGUMENT: at crypter_ops.cc:33: mechanism 0x1 is not valid for operation decrypt [type.googleapis.com/kmsp11.StatusDetails='CK_RV=0x70']
java.security.InvalidKeyException: init() failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implInit(P11RSACipher.java:239)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.engineInit(P11RSACipher.java:168)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:867)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1252)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1189)
    at engsec.cmds.EncryptKMS.run(EncryptKMS.java:73)
    at engsec.App.main(App.java:34)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_DecryptInit(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.initialize(P11RSACipher.java:323)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implInit(P11RSACipher.java:237)
    ... 7 more
```

The code is below:

```
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
            ks.load(null, null);

            Key privateKey = ks.getKey(
                    PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS,
                    null
            );

            Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher2.init(
                    Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                    privateKey
            );
            byte[] clearText = cipher2.doFinal(cipherBytes);

            System.out.println("Decrypted value: ", new String(clearText));
```

How to fix the exception?
Is it possible to integrate Java Ecosystem and Cloud KMS for establishing mTLS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the key at `PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS` refers to a signing key in Cloud KMS (that is, a key with the `ASYMMETRIC_SIGN` purpose), then it cannot be used for decryption.